# Как изменить шаблон не только для категории?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня имеется код, который позволяет использовать категории кастомный шаблон, но при этом у этой категории есть еще и подкатегории, а в них еще подкатегории и т.д.

**Как переделать код, чтобы данный шаблон распространялся и на подкатегории?**

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }

    // Get current category slug
    global $wp_query;
    $cat_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];

    // Call template conditionally
    if($cat_slug == 'zakaznaya-produktsiya') {
        wc_get_template( 'archive-custom.php' );
    } else  {
        wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );   
    }
?>
```

Comment: category__not_in

Comment: @SeVlad как правильно записать, если использовать данный код?

Comment: Читай ман по wp_query

Comment: Да код шляпа, удалил ответ. У меня тоже не сработало.